# Serializing an ISerializable object, that contains other ISerializable-objects

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm currently working on saving larger object structures which contain all the data needed for a 'project' in the application I'm working on. The data are things such as pictures, flowdocuments as well as the more basic datatypes.

Now, my current approach has been implementing ISerializable on all classes that are contained within the object that I need saving. However, when:

```
public class Profile : ISerializable
{
    public ObservableCollection<Trade> Trades { get; set; }

    public Profile() {}

    public Profile(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
            : this()
        {    
            foreach (SerializationEntry entry in info)
            {
                if (entry.Name.StartsWith("trade"))
                {
                    Type t = entry.ObjectType;
                    Trades.Add(entry.Value as Trade);
                }
            }
        }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (Trade t in Trades)
            {
                info.AddValue("trade" + i, t, t.GetType());
                i++;
            }
        }
}
```

it poses a problem. The Trade-class that is what populates my List also implements ISerializable. So what I'm wonder is: is this a good approach? Does it even work? The code I've written so far doesn't work, and I'm still trying to work out the kinks.

More specifically will the info.AddValue("trade" + i, t, t.GetType()); use the Trade-class' ISerializable-methods? Or perhaps this interface wasn't even meant to deal with these types of classes.

So if anyone would be so kind, and take a little look and maybe point me in the correct direction when it comes to Serialization of things such as these.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the problem here is exactly (if you can post the Trade class and details on what exactly is not working it would be helpful), but in general if the Trade class is serializable, you should be able to just add the [Serializable] attribute to the Profile class and do not need to do custom serialization by implementing ISerializable.

Usually you only need to implement ISerializable when you need to do custom serialization (e.g. when your data members are not serializable).

Edit:
 Just realized you are using an ObservableCollection so my previous comment of just using [Serializable] attribute is not correct. See here for info on serializing ObservableCollection: http://kentb.blogspot.com/2007/11/serializing-observablecollection.html or you should also be able to use ObservableCollection.CopyTo() to get a Trade[] instance and add that directly to the SerializationInfo.

Comment: It's more a general question and not something specific, and this is just an example code-snippet. Sorry if I was unclear. The question: If I have class that I need to do custom serialization on, and then that class contains objects that also require custom serialization how do I deal with that in the GetObjectData-method? Or perhaps that isn't even a problem? Wondering if perhaps something like DataContractSerializer and stuff like that is needed or not. Thanks

Comment: In general, each class should be in charge of its own serialization (custom or default) and classes that contain serializable classes should not need to know or care how it is done, it is encapsulated. You may be running into trouble due to serializing the ObservableCollection, and there is more info about that here: http://kentb.blogspot.com/2007/11/serializing-observablecollection.html. If you just need to serialize the Types, the you should be able to do use ObservableCollection.CopyTo() to get a Trade[] and add that directly to the SerializationInfo.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. CopyTo(), should probably be enough. I didn't know that was possible. I thought I had to serialize every object in the list individually if they were anything other than the basic types.